# Can I iterate over a multidimensional enum (java)?

Tags: java, data-structures, enums, multidimensional-array

I've got an Enum as follows (the actual one is much bigger):

```
public enum PricesType {

    SMALL("Small",
            new BigDecimal(     "9.69"      ),
            new BigDecimal(     "11.49"     ),
            new BigDecimal(     "13.39"     ),
            new BigDecimal(     "22.79"     ),
    MEDIUM("Medium",
            new BigDecimal(     "18.19"     ),
            new BigDecimal(     "27.99"     ),
            new BigDecimal(     "35.99"     ),
            new BigDecimal(     "44.89"     );
    String size;
    BigDecimal monthToMonth;
    BigDecimal sixMonth;
    BigDecimal twelveMonth;
    BigDecimal twentyFourMonth;
... constructors, methods...}
```

Is there an easy way for me to iterate the multidimensional aspect of this?  I know how to iterate by size, but how do I iterate through the various months?

That is, I can do :

```
for (PricesType o: PricesType.values()){
  System.out.println(o); // gives me the "SMALL" "MEDIUM" etc.
}
```

But can I loop through the months with some index/ iterator or do I **HAVE** to call each individually?  (I've got a lot of these).

Maybe a better data structure?  It's for a price list that is kept in memory until something triggers a change.

Comment: ...You could just pass into the `enum` constructor a list or a map of those values...

Answer (score 0):

I would use an array

```
 SMALL("Small",
        BigDecimal.valueOf(9.69),
        BigDecimal.valueOf(11.49),
        BigDecimal.valueOf(13.39),
        BigDecimal.valueOf(22.79));

 private final String size;
 private final BigDecimal[] values;

 PricesType(String size, BigDecimal... values) {
     this.size = size; this.values = values;
 }
```

This way you can iterate over every entry in a loop.

I would use `double` unless you need more than 15 digits of accuracy.

```
 SMALL("Small", 9.69, 11.49, 13.39, 22.79);

 private final String size;
 private final double[] values;

 PricesType(String size, double... values) {
     this.size = size; this.values = values;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the Collection API instead, which gives you plenty of options to iterate through values, in your case, a Map would be best.

```
Map<PriceType, Set<BigDecimal>> priceMap = new HashMap<PriceType, Set<BigDecimal>>();
    priceMap.put(PriceType.SMALL, Sets.newHashSet(
        new BigDecimal(     "9.69"      ),
        new BigDecimal(     "11.49"     ),
        new BigDecimal(     "13.39"     ),
        new BigDecimal(     "22.79"     )
    ));

public enum PriceType {
    SMALL, MEDIUM, LARGE;
}
```

Comment: Yes, but you'd only need it for that neat initialization for the Set. Any standard Java way should work.